# is this actually a resource leak?

Tags: java, mysql

I have an "Invitation" object that is modeled in a MySQL database.  This object has one list ("treatmentPlanIDsToCopyf") and is maintained in the database with a second table. The method I have written to insert into the main table and then loop through the list and insert records for each item in the list into the second table is below.  At the line `ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);`Eclipse is giving me a warning that says "Resource leak: 'ps' is not closed at this location".  I am closing the prepared statement in the `finally` clause, so I wanted to know if there really is a resource leak I need to fix.  This is my first time using batches with prepared statements, so I wasn't really sure.  Thanks.

```
public void invitationCreate(Connection cn, Invitation invitation) throws SQLException{

    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
        //first insert primary invitation data into the invitation table
        String sql = "INSERT INTO invitiation (invitation_code, recipient_email, sender_user_id_fk, date_intived, date_accepted, accepted, recipient_first_name, recipient_last_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setString(1, invitation.getInvitationCode());
        ps.setString(2, invitation.getRecipientEmail());
        ps.setInt(3, invitation.getSenderUserID());
        ps.setTimestamp(4, convertLocalTimeDateToTimstamp(invitation.getDateInvited()));
        ps.setTimestamp(5, convertLocalTimeDateToTimstamp(invitation.getDateAccepted()));
        ps.setBoolean(6, invitation.isAccepted());
        ps.setString(7, invitation.getRecipientFirstName());
        ps.setString(8, invitation.getRecipientLastName());

        int success = ps.executeUpdate();

        //now loop through all the treatmentPlanIDs in the invitation that are to be copied into the invitees account when the register

        sql = "INSERT INTO invitation_treatment_plans (invitation_code_fk, invitation_treatment_plan_id_fk) VALUES (?, ?)";

        ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);//TODO confirm this if this is actually a resource leak

        for(int treatmentPlanID : invitation.getTreatmentPlanIDsToCopy()){
            ps.setString(1, invitation.getInvitationCode());
            ps.setInt(2, treatmentPlanID);

            ps.addBatch();
        }

        ps.executeBatch();

    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(ps);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the leak is in the first prepared statement.

After `int success = ps.executeUpdate();` you need to close that prepared statement before you assign the variable to a new prepared statement.